# How to resize the array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I have been trying to create my own `Array` class, which is dynamic, but I can't figure out the problem
in resizing the size of it. I created separate function to check if the array is full and for resizing it. But I think it is unable to call either one of those.

```
public class Array {
    private int[] array;
    private int size;
    public int pointer;
    private static int DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;
    
    Array() {
        this(DEFAULT_SIZE);
    }
    
    Array(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        this.array = new int[size];
    }
    
    public void add(int element) {
        if (isFull()) {
            resize();
        }
        array[pointer] = element;
        pointer++;
    }

    private boolean isFull() {
        return pointer == array.length;
    }

    private void resize() {
        int[] temp = new int[size * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
            temp[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = temp;
    }
    
    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)).

Comment: What *is* the actual problem? At first glance, the code looks fine.

Comment: How are you determining that "it is not calling either of those"?

Comment: Hehe... the propgram never updates field `size`. If we replace `int[] temp = new int[size * 2];` with `size *= 2; int[] temp = new int[size];`, the program works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are never updating the `size` after allocating the bigger array:

```
private void resize() {
    int[] temp = new int[size * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
        temp[i] = array[i];
    }
    array = temp;   
}
```

This will leave `size` at the initial value of `5`. You have to add `size *= 2` at the end of your method (or at the start and then only do `new int[size]`).

Please note that the `size` field is totally redundant, because it is already tracked and accessible via `array.length` (which you are already using in your loop's condition).

`print` seems to be incorrect, as it always prints the full array, even the items which have not been added yet. You likely want to user `pointer` instead of `size` (otherwise, you are going to print lots of zeros):

```
public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pointer; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite redundant: he figured out it's not very efficient to resize each time he adds an element, and switched to amortized reallocation (that's why the new allocated size if `size*2`). You have then to keep track of the storage size, and the actual array size. So it's not `size *= 2` but `size++` (only one more actual element, even though the array size is larger than that): useful for printing the array without the extra elements in `print`, for instance. However `size` may be redundant with `pointer`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes, we already have `pointer` and `array.length`. `size == array.length` is always true, except for a few statements while resizing; here a local variable would work – and would have perhaps avoided this error (i.e. forgetting to update size)

Comment: No, `size == array.length` must not be true, otherwise `print` is wrong. With the current code, we shoud have `size == pointer`: `pointer` is incremented **after** adding in `add`, and the test is `pointer == array.length` in `isFull`, so `pointer` is the first index past the last element, hence equal to `size`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut sorry, but `size` is the array's length: `this.size = size; this.array = new int[size];` and in resize (`temp = new int[size*2]` – with missing update of size to the new value). `pointer` is the "current size", `size` is the "current/max capacity". `pointer` is 1 after adding the first element (i.e. calling `add` once); `size` on the other hand will be 5 (given the default constructor was used). Unless I'm totally missing the point here. (note that `print` was implemented incorrectly too)

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong. You don't quite get the idea of amortized allocation, apparently. In `print` the loop is up to `size`. But there are usually elements after that, so usually `size < array.length` (and you don't want to print element that were not added to the array but are just placeholders for future additions). The idea is to allocate more than necessary to avoid allocating each time an element is added.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut but the print loop is wrong. It must only iterate up to `pointer`, not `size`. `size` is always the total allocated space (the "capacity") and `pointer` is the current "size" of the array (i.e. the number of non-empty slots, or number of elements). Please read the code of OP carefully. Other implementations might call the number of elements `size`, but for this implementation it's not the case. `pointer` is what you call "size" and `size` is the capacity (what gives us "amortized allocation")